# Power using recursion c++

Tags: c++, recursion, math

I wrote this code for calculating power of a number using recursion and it works with integers but when i pass a float, it doesn't give me an error it returns the wrong value.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int powerRec(float num, int power)
{
    if(power<=0)
        return 1;
    return num*powerRec(num, --power);
}
int main()
{
    int power;
    float num, powerRec_;
    cout<<"Enter number and the power you want it to be raised: "<<endl;
    cin>>num>>power;
    powerRec_ = powerRec(num, power);
    cout<<"Result: "<<powerRec_<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `powerRec` function returns an `int`. That should probably be a `float`.

Comment: I also used double instead of float but it still gives wrong output with floats. For example if I pass num = 3.5 and power = 4, it returns 122 which is wrong. It should return 150.0625

Comment: @Darhuuk How do i make it return a float?

Comment: in the definition of your function ie `int powerRec(float num, int power)` change it to be `float powerRec(float num, int power)` That is how to make your function return a float

Comment: @Onyambu yes it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type of `powerRec` is `int`, so the returned value will be truncated.

Use return type `float` to do calculation properly.

Comment: Or  use `double` to get more precision in answer.

Comment: Note that you need to convert all of the `float`s in the function to `double`. Doing math on `float`s and then popping the result into a `double` doesn't get you much of an improvement. Too much data has already been lost.